# How to run the statement after reloading the page in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, reload

I have some few lines of codes which I want to run after page reload.

```
function showServicesList(){
    location.reload();

    /*
    *   Statement1
    *   Statement2
    *   Statement3
    *   Statement4
    */
}
```

Page is refreshing, but the statement below after `location.reload` doesn't execute. Any help in this ?

Comment: `location.reload()` will immediately reload the page as if you had reloaded/refreshed it manually. Any context is lost and you're script execution is halted never making it to any other statement.

Comment: Do you only want to run the rest of the code after the reload or would it be ok to run it on first load?

Comment: I want to run the rest of the code after reload.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well. If you reload your page, any JavaScript is stopped and reloaded too. If you want your code to run AFTER the page is reloaded you could add a hash.

```
window.location.hash = "triggerReloadCode";
window.location.reload();

if (window.location.hash.substr(1) == "triggerReloadCode") {
    window.location.hash = "";
    /* Statements */
}
```

I don't know if that's best practice, but I would trigger it like this.

Comment: Ok.. let me try .. I will let u know

Comment: No.. I am getting the same result. Code is not running

Comment: You have to exclude the if-section outside the function where it is called on page-load (for example at the top of your script (without any function around). Or you put it in a function which is called on page-load. The 2 upper lines can remain in your function: http://jsfiddle.net/VP9NV/