# Radio button after page reload in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, reload

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input[type=radio]").change(function(){                           
var tip_user = $("input[name=user_tp]:checked").val();
document.cookie = 'user_tip=' + tip_user;
location.reload();
});
});
</script>
```

I have the code above. After page reload, the radio button is not checked. I want the radio button to be checked at `tip_user` value. I tried `$(this).val(tip_user)` after `location.reload()` but the code doesn't work. What code to add inside or outside the code above in order to check radio button at `tip_user` value.

Comment: This link will helpful for you [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23785894/run-the-codes-after-reoading-the-page-in-jquery)